How to add div or text in svg tag, which I imported from gatewaves.io?

I want to add div or text in svg tag ,which imported from getwaves.io, I have added but not showing.

import React from "react";
import "../styles/About.css";

const About = () => {
  return (
    <div className=" ">
      <div className="row dip1">
        <h3>We serve in following technologies</h3>
        <p>Reactjs</p>
        <p>Wordpress</p>
        <p>PHP</p>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
          <path
            fill="#FFFFFF"
            fill-opacity="1"
            d="M0,160L48,149.3C96,139,192,117,288,122.7C384,128,480,160,576,186.7C672,213,768,235,864,202.7C960,171,1056,85,1152,53.3C1248,21,1344,43,1392,53.3L1440,64L1440,320L1392,320C1344,320,1248,320,1152,320C1056,320,960,320,864,320C768,320,672,320,576,320C480,320,384,320,288,320C192,320,96,320,48,320L0,320Z"
          ></path>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default About;

I added div tag in between svt tag and also path tag , but both of these not working. I want to show text in svg screen.

If your goal is to just add text to svg screen then create a text element below or above svg and then position it with position: absolute; or any other property.

I want to add div so that card can be display in that svg div, kindly show how can I do it ?

Can you add image of what you really want because I am finding hard to understand what exactly is your goal.

The code you show doesn't have any text within the svg. Could you show us exactly what you have tried.

Besides using position:absolute suggested by @Meet, one possible way to display text or even html content in the svg tag is through foreignObject tags.
Using your codes,
import React from "react";
import "../styles/About.css";

const About = () => {
  return (
    <div className=" ">
      <div className="row dip1">
        <h3>We serve in following technologies</h3>
        <p>Reactjs</p>
        <p>Wordpress</p>
        <p>PHP</p>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
          <path
            fill="#FFFFFF"
            fill-opacity="1"
            d="M0,160L48,149.3C96,139,192,117,288,122.7C384,128,480,160,576,186.7C672,213,768,235,864,202.7C960,171,1056,85,1152,53.3C1248,21,1344,43,1392,53.3L1440,64L1440,320L1392,320C1344,320,1248,320,1152,320C1056,320,960,320,864,320C768,320,672,320,576,320C480,320,384,320,288,320C192,320,96,320,48,320L0,320Z"
          ></path>
          /* REMARK: Use the `foreignObject` tag, with manual `width` and `height` properties */
          <foreignObject x="200" y="250" width="200" height="200">
            <div>The text or HTML content you want to display, right here.</div>
          </foreignObject>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default About;

Through this method, you can even embed forms or other html tags inside the svg. For example,
const About = () => {
  return (
    /* ...other content */
    <foreignObject x="50" y="50" width="200" height="150">
        <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <form>
                <input type="text"/>
                <input type="button"/>
            </form>
        </body>
    </foreignObject>
    /* ...other content */
  );
}


P.S.1 For the scope that foreignObject tag can support, check this: What can be rendered in foreignObject element when SVG is embedded in HTML5?
P.S.2 For using plain JavaScript methods to embed texts in svg, check this: how to change svg text tag using javascript innerHTML

I have already applied  foreignObject but its not working.

@ParasChouhan Please show your codes with the foreignObject tag? Remember to put your foreignObject tag at last if the two collides, so the content will stay on top.

Besides, manually setting the width and height of the foreignObject tag might help.

As you mentioned , foreignObject below path tag in svg tag

@ParasChouhan Try manually setting the width and height; I also noticed that your svg is in total white, you might have to set the div color to others too.
